# ¿Como puedo imprimir un array de objetos con este codigo? en Java

Tags: java, array, objeto

Quiero imprimir al usuario un array de objetos despues de pasar los valores en parametros por el usuario, tengo esta clase que crea los array, agrega y tendria que imprimirlos cuando se llame al metodo.

```
package Data;

public class teatro {

public Lugares[] asientoPalco;
public Lugares[] asientoPrincipal;
public Lugares[] asientoCentral;
public Lugares[] asientoLateral;



public teatro() {
    Palco();
    Central();
    Lateral();
    Principal();
}

private void Palco() {
    asientoPalco = new Lugares[40];
}
private void Central() {
    asientoCentral = new Lugares[60];
}
private void Lateral() {
    asientoLateral = new Lugares[30];
}
private void Principal() {
    asientoPrincipal = new Lugares[50];
}

public void addAsiento(String zona, String nombre, int costo ) {
    int i;
    if (zona=="palco"){
        
    for(i=0;i<=40;i++) {
        if (asientoPalco[i]==null) {
        asientoPalco[i]=new Lugares(zona, costo, nombre, i);
        }
        else if(asientoPalco[40]!=null){
            System.out.println("No hay lugares disponibles");
        }
        
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    }
    else if (zona=="central"){
        for(i=0;i<=60;i++) {
            if (asientoCentral[i]==null) {
            asientoCentral[i]=new Lugares(zona, costo, nombre, i);
            }
            else if(asientoCentral[60]!=null){
                System.out.println("No hay lugares disponibles");
            }
            
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        }
    if (zona=="lateral"){
        for(i=0;i<=30;i++) {
            if (asientoLateral[i]==null) {
            asientoLateral[i]=new Lugares(zona, costo, nombre, i);
            }
            else if(asientoLateral[30]!=null){
                System.out.println("No hay lugares disponibles");
            }
            
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        }
    if (zona=="central"){
        for(i=0;i<=50;i++) {
            if (asientoPrincipal[i]==null) {
            asientoPalco[i]=new Lugares(zona, costo, nombre, i);
            }
            else if(asientoPrincipal[50]!=null){
                System.out.println("No hay lugares disponibles");
            }
            
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        }
}

public void getAsientos(int id, String zona) {
    if (zona=="central"){
        System.out.println((asientoCentral[id].toString()));
    }
    else if (zona=="palco"){
        System.out.println((asientoPalco[id].toString()));
    }
    else if (zona=="lateral"){
        System.out.println((asientoLateral[id].toString()));
    }
    else if (zona=="principal"){
        System.out.println((asientoPrincipal[id].toString()));
    }
    }

public void getAll() {
        System.out.println(("palco: "+asientoPalco.toString())+"\n");
        System.out.println(("central: "+asientoCentral.toString())+"\n");
        System.out.println(("principal: "+asientoPrincipal.toString())+"\n");
        System.out.println(("Lateral: "+asientoLateral.toString())+"\n");
    }
}
```

Lo que pretendo con esta clase es crear los 4 arrays, agregar asientos cada vez que alguien compra un boleto, verificar si hay lugar e ir registrandolos, y por ultimo imprimir cada uno o todos los arrays.

Esta es mi clase de lugares por si se necesita

```
package Data;

 public class Lugares {

 private String zona;
    private int precio;
    private String nombre;
    private int idCliente;
    
    public Lugares(String zona, int precio, String nombre, int idCliente){
        this.zona = zona;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
    }

    public String getZona(){
        return zona;
    }

    public void setZona(String zona){
        this.zona = zona;
    }

    public int getPrecio(){
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(int precio){
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getIdCliente(){
        return idCliente;
    }

    public void setIdCliente(int idCliente){
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
    }
    
    
    public String toString(){
        return "\nZona escogida: \n"+zona+"\n Precio establecido: "+precio+"\n Nombre del 
cliente: "+nombre+"\n Id: "+idCliente;
    }
}
```

y por ultimo el main:

```
package Data;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Venta {

Venta(){
    
}

public void Main() {
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
     
     int precio=0, opcion=0;
    
     boolean salir=false;

    
    String zona = null, zon1=null;
    
    teatro Teatro= new teatro();
    
    
    while (!salir) {
         
        System.out.println("1. Cpmprar");
        System.out.println("2. Consultar");
        System.out.println("3. Consultar por zona");
        System.out.println("4. Cnacelar");
       

        try {

            System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
            opcion = sn.nextInt();

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre");
                    
                    String nombre = sn.nextLine();
                    nombre = sn.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese su edad");
                    int edad= sn.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese la zona 1.Principal 2.Palco 3.Central 
     4.Lateral (Escribe el nombre)");
                    zona = sn.nextLine();
                    zona = sn.nextLine();
                    if (zona.toLowerCase()=="palco") {
                        if (validacion(nombre, edad)==true) {
                            precio = 4000;
                        }
                        else{
                            precio=7000;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (zona.toLowerCase()=="principal") {
                        if (validacion(nombre, edad)==true) {
                            precio = 1750;
                        }
                        else{
                            precio=2500;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (zona.toLowerCase()=="central") {
                        if (validacion(nombre, edad)==true) {
                            precio = 1400;
                        }
                        else{
                            precio=2000;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (zona.toLowerCase()=="lateral") {
                        if (validacion(nombre, edad)==true) {
                            precio = 1000;
                        }
                        else{
                            precio=1550;
                        }
                    }

                    
                    Teatro.addAsiento(zona, nombre, precio);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Introduce la zona de la entrada:");
                    zon1 = sn.nextLine();
                    zon1 = sn.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Introduce el ID de la entrada:");
                    int idEntrada = sn.nextInt();
                    Teatro.getAsientos(idEntrada, zona);
                    
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Estos son los asientos ocupados: ");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Ingresa el ID de la entrada a cancelar");
                    int idCancelar =sn.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("ID a cancelar"+idCancelar);
                    System.out.println("Asiento Eliminado");
                default:
                    System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 4");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Debes insertar un número");
            sn.next();
        }
    }
    

}

public boolean validacion(String nombre, int edad) {
    Persona cliente = new Persona(nombre, edad);
    if (cliente.Descuento(edad)==true){
        return true;
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Venta().Main();
    
}
}
```

Se que es un poco desordenado y no tan optimizado pero quisiera saber porque cuando se llama al metodo de imprimir no lo hace. Agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: ¿Esto es un ejercicio? Pregunto porque si  no lo es hay formas más sencillas de organizar esto. Por ejemplo, no hay necesidad de recorrer todo el array cada vez que haya que agregar un elemento. Sea como sea, hablas de un método *imprimir* que no aparece en el código. ¿A qué te refieres con eso? Explica también qué hace el código (¿se queda la pantalla en blanco?, ¿muestra error? ¿qué error?, .... etc ...)

Comment: Es un ejercicio de la escuela, soy bastante nuevo, en la parte de getAsientos en la clase teatro, pense que al utilizar la funcion de los arrays getString y llamarlo en un println saldria en consola, sin embargo cuando llamo al caso 2 en el menu no imprime nada

Comment: En el caso 2, ¿qué valor estás pasando en el argumento zona al método getAsientos? Veo dos variables zon1 pero no veo claro de donde viene zona. El case 4 no tiene break. Y por último, para imprimir un array, tienes que recorrerlo e ir imprimiendo cada uno de sus elementos. El método toString de un array no tiene los efectos que tú pretendes, no te va a imprimir todos sus elementos.

Comment: Corregi ese valor de zon1, se supone que ya esta recibiendo la zona que debe seleccionar el usuario, entiendo lo de imprimir todos con una iteración, sin embargo no comprendo por que en el metodo getAsiento no imprime el elemento del array que elijo, escribo el input como debe de estar para que entren las condiciones y aun así no imprime en consola ese elemento

Comment: Todos los `if` en el método `getAsientos()` están mal. **Toma nota de esto y no lo olvides nunca: cuando vas a comparar cadenas en Java debes usar el método `equals()`**. Una comparación como esta o similar nunca te funcionará: `if (zona=="central"){`, porque los String no son valores primitivos, el método propio para compararlos es este: `if(zona.equals("central")){` debes cambiar igualmente todas las comparaciones de cadenas que estés haciendo con `==`